# Работа с почтой. Smtplib сколько отправлено байт

Tags: python, smtp

Отправляю почту с помощью MIMEMultipart() и smtplib.SMTP().
Можно ли как-нибудь узнать сколько байт письма уже отправлено?
Хочу сделать индикатор хода процесса.

Answer (score 1):

Такая возможность не предусмотрена. `smtplib` использует метод [`socket.sendall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall), который не возвращается до тех пор, пока все данные не отправлены или не возникла ошибка.

Можно переопределить метод [`SMTP.send()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/94e24be943d7cd280f4471022d22557d50ef2752/Lib/smtplib.py#L342-L358) в дочернем классе, чтобы вместо `self.sock.sendall(s)` использовался `n = self.sock.send(chunk)` в цикле и `t.update(n)` по завершению каждого `.send()`, устанавливая `t.total = len(s)` в начале цикла, где `t` это объект из модуля [`tqdm`](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#documentation) (читается как «такадум») — можно иметь несколько вложенных progress bar, одна общая для письма и подчинённые для каждого `self.send()` вызова (для каждой smtp команды).

Набросок (не тестирован):

```
import smtplib
import tqdm  # $ pip install tqdm

class SMTP(smptlib.SMTP):
    def send(self, s):
        if isinstance(s, str):
            s = s.encode(self.command_encoding)
        try:
            sendall_with_progress(self.sock, s)
        except OSError:
            self.close()
            raise SMTPServerDisconnected('Server not connected')


def sendall_with_progress(sock, data, chunksize=1<<15):
    with tqdm.tqdm(total=len(data), unit='B', unit_scale=True, miniters=1) as t:
        for chunk in (data[i:i+chunksize] for i in range(0, t.total, chunksize)):
            sock.sendall(chunk) #NOTE: allow OSError to propagate
            t.update(len(chunk))
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Прогресс бар нужен только один. Не могли бы вы привести примерный код?

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться